# Websphere - Performance Monitoring Infrastructure servlet login GET

Tags: application-server

I am trying to make an http call to the WebSphere PMI servlet.
Websphere has security enabled and therefore I am asked to enter user credentials in order to display the xml.
What actually doesn't work as I expect is that username and password in the url are not recognized and the BASIC authorization form is displayed.
Obviously it doesn't work from a third party application point of view, I need to pass those variables as GET request.

Any suggestion?

Comment: We have found a work around, instead of passing parameters into the url (as docs described) we used basic authentication on client.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's not using basic authentication... perhaps cookie session based...
what are you hitting it with?  wget? curl? perl?

There are perl modules that can emulate a browser and you can write a script to navigate thru the login and fetch the XML you want.  Google 'perldoc WWW::Mechanize'

Would love to hear of solutions that require less module installation, however.